# Error while implementing the Mediapipe.solution.hands

Tags: python, opencv, contour, mediapipe

I'm trying to implement a hand detection by pose estimation of gesture using mediapipe in a particular contour Area. So i converted the detected skeleton to grayscale as findcontour will work only with grayscale.

But while detecting the hands, after few frames detection of gesture receiving the following error:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
E20220609 12:41:04.193675 14822 calculator_graph.cc:770] INVALID_ARGUMENT: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_gestures.py", line 120, in <module>
  File "create_gestures.py", line 65, in store_images
  File "/data/basestl/Pose base slt-base/Mediapipee.py", line 19, in drawHand
  File "/home/cdac/.virtualenvs/cdacAI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solutions/hands.py", line 164, in process
  File "/home/cdac/.virtualenvs/cdacAI/lib/python3.6/site-`packages`/mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 307, in process
ValueError: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run: 
Calculator::Open() for node "handlandmarkcpu__TensorsToClassificationCalculator" failed: ; 
Can't find file: /home/cdac/.virtualenvs/cdacAI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mediapipe/modules/hand_landmark/handedness.txt
```

I don't how to solve and i even verified that the following handedness.txt is available in the mentioned location.

And even i can't able to detect the thumbs sign properly as its hangs and its improper.

Please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Please include the code you are using.

Comment: black_flag = eval("True")   #global black_flag
rgbIMG = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
self.results = self.hands.process(rgbIMG)
# print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
image = img.copy()
if black_flag:
    img = img * 0
    if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
       for hand in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            if draw:
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, hand,self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(image, hand, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
   return image,img

Comment: This is snippet of my code.. But i can't share all code as its contains 1000 lines of code